# Настройка библиотеки SDL2 в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl2

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. Я скачал с официального сайта SDL2 for Visual C++. Подключил к проекту полностью по инструкции (прописал *SDL2.lib*, *SDL2main.lib*, путь к папке *include*, путь *SDL2/lib/x86*, подсистема - консоль, dll закинул в *Debug*). Библиотека через #include подключается, даже можно что-то написать, но при компиляции выдает **Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _SDL_main в функции _main_getcmdline SDL_Project**. Пробовал скачивать с разных источников, отчаявшись, даже переустанавливал Visual Studio (2017). Скажите, что я мог по невнимательности сделать не так?

Comment: У вас `main` объявлена как `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, или как-то иначе? SDL, из-за кое-каких трюков с макросами, к этому чувствительна.

Comment: Боже. Я объявлял int main(). Я понимал что SDL использует макрос для main, но не думал что это аргументы важны. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в макросах. [Этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976084/why-sdl-defines-main-macro) можно считать похожим.

`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`